# Having issue with the line

Tags: php

I got this error when i upload it to the FTP,
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in `/home/user/public_html/ref/hhhhh_hhhhh/index.php` on line 15

Any idea what's wrong?

```
<?php       
require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';
$api_key = 'apikey';
$api_url = 'url';
$client = new jsonRPCClient($api_url);
$campaigns = $client->get_campaigns(
    $api_key,
    array (
        # find by name literally
        'name' => array ( 'EQUALS' => 'test' )
    )
);
$CAMPAIGN_ID = array_pop(array_keys($campaigns));
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $result = $client->add_contact(
    $api_key,
    array (
        'campaign'  => $CAMPAIGN_ID,
        'name'      => 'Test',
        'email'     => 'test@test.test',
    )
    );
$cid = "infod";
$site_url = $cid.".pokemon.com";    
header("Location: http://$site_url") ;
}

?>
```

Comment: The topic of your question isn't really constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = $client->add_contact(
$api_key,
array (
    'campaign'  => $CAMPAIGN_ID,
    'name'      => 'Test',
    'email'     => 'test@test.test',
)
); /* <- missed the ";" */
```

Comment: now i have this error :
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/user/public_html/ref/hhhhh_hhhhh/index.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$CAMPAIGN_ID = array_pop(array_keys($campaigns));
```

to

```
$CAMPAIGN_ID = array_keys($campaigns);
$CAMPAIGN_ID = array_pop($CAMPAIGN_ID);
```

and see if it helps.